# How get get data "orderBy" months but start with Current month and so on

Tags: laravel

Trying to get data by months and for the first part, it's working perfectly and is now stuck at 2 points.

1. Required Month Name  with Year ( Say "March 2022" )
2. Required the same in OrderBy where it should start with the current month (March 2022) and then further (April 2022, May 2022, June 2022 .... Jan 2022, Feb 2022)

My Controller

```
         $getdatapermonth    =   Dairyincome::select(
            DB::raw('(MONTHNAME(date)) as "month_name",SUM(cmilkquantity) as "cmilkquantity", SUM(cmilkamount) as "cmilkamount",SUM(bmilkquantity) as "bmilkquantity", SUM(bmilkamount) as "bmilkamount", SUM(totalamount) as "totalamount"')
            )
            ->where('customerid',$customerid)   
            ->whereYear('date', date('Y'))
            ->groupBy('month_name')
            ->get()->toArray();
```

Array I am getting

```
array:3 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
    "month_name" => "January"
    "cmilkquantity" => "0.00"
    "cmilkamount" => "0.00"
    "bmilkquantity" => "10.00"
    "bmilkamount" => "450.00"
    "totalamount" => "450.00"
     ]
     1 => array:6 [▼
    "month_name" => "February"
    "cmilkquantity" => "2.00"
    "cmilkamount" => "70.00"
    "bmilkquantity" => "0.00"
    "bmilkamount" => "0.00"
    "totalamount" => "70.00"
     ]
     2 => array:6 [▼
    "month_name" => "March"
    "cmilkquantity" => "2.00"
    "cmilkamount" => "70.00"
    "bmilkquantity" => "2.00"
    "bmilkamount" => "70.00"
    "totalamount" => "140.00"
  ]
]
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure about adding previous months after current month and further months?? Or, you want to omit previous months?

Comment: Actually i was wroung, cant remove the previous moths... Can u help me to show Month name with Year Like March 2022.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
DB::raw('(MONTHNAME(date)) as "month_name"')
```

to:

```
DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%M %Y") as "month_name"')
```

It will output month name in "Month YYYY" format.